# How to use switchIfEmpty?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I need to fetch data from DB. If it's empty, get data from server and insert it into database.
Here is my code,

```
public Flowable<List<Data>> test() {
    return dataDao.allDatas()
           .switchIfEmpty(datas())
                .doOnNext(datas -> userStoreDao.insert(datas))
           );
}

public Flowable<List<Data>> datas() {
    return Flowable.zip(userFavoriteDatas(), userOtherDatas(),
        (favoriteDatas, otherDatas) -> {
            favoriteDatas.addAll(otherDatas);
            return favoriteDatas;
        });
}

public Flowable<List<Data>> userFavoriteDatas() {
    return userDatas()
        .map(UserDatas::favoriteDatas)
        .flatMapIterable(datas-> datas)
        .map(aLong -> new UserData(aLong, 1))
        .toList()
        .toFlowable();
}

public Flowable<List<Data>> userOtherDatas() {
    return userDatas()
        .map(UserDatas::otherDatas)
        .flatMapIterable(datas-> datas)
        .map(aLong -> new UserData(aLong, 1))
        .toList()
        .toFlowable();
}

private Flowable<Datas> userDatas() {
    return api
        .userDatas()
        .toFlowable()
        .share(); 
}

@GET("user/datas")
Single<Datas> datas();
```

It  reaches second part when the first part returns empty result. datas() doesn't reached till the end while I'm running only the second part it works but combining with switchIfEmpty() it reaches to userDatas() and doesn't complete

I tried `concat()` as well with the same result.

Comment: How is `allDatas()` empty? You mean it emits an empty `List`? `dataDao.allDatas().filter(list -> !list.isEmpty()).switchIfEmpty(...)` should work.

Comment: @akarnokd,
yes the problem is another 
in switchIfEmpty it is not just call to backend it contains Flowable.zip()
when I'm running that part without using switchIfEmpty it works but combining with switchIfEmpty it doesn't  completes. what do you think ?

Comment: I think you should provide a standalone code example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Akarnokd I have updated my question.

Comment: What does `dataDao.allDatas()` return? Please run just `dataDao.allDatas().subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("Done"))`.

Comment: @akamokd
 
it returns empty with size= 0 list, as I mentioned it It reaches second part when the first part returns empty result. datas() (second part) doesn't reached till the end while I'm running only the second part it works but combining with switchIfEmpty() it reaches to userDatas() and doesn't complete –

Comment: So does every Flowable complete on its own but the sequence doesn't complete if you use `switchIfEmpty`? I can't see why that would be the case unless there are things involved you are not showing. Please provide a standalone, **runnable** unit test that demonstrates your problem. You should mock out the API calls with some `just(value)`.

Comment: @akarnokd Yes, it is not complete with switchIfEmpty,it stops on userDatas() method

Comment: Time to add some `doOnNext(System.out::println)` and `doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Done"))` to the flow in `userDatas` to see what events are propagates. Add the before, in-between and just before returning.

Comment: return api.userDatas()
                .doOnEvent((userDatas, throwable) -> Log.i("test", "" + userDatas))
        .doOnError(throwable -> Log.i("test", "" + throwable))

it prints nothing,but without switchIfEmpty() it works

Comment: Are you sure you filtered out the empty `List` from `dataDao.allDatas()` properly? I.e., `filter(list -> list.size() == 0)` or `filter(list -> ! list.isEmpty())`? Does `allDatas` complete at all? Could you try `allDatas.take(1).filter(...)`?

Comment: @akarnokd Adding take(1) solve my problem ,Thanks ,could you give me short explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(From the comments):

If you use `toList`, that requires a finite stream. Based on the OP's feedback, the `allDatas` source was infinite but returned an empty `List`. The resolution was to apply at least `take(1)` to get exactly one response from `allDatas` and
then optionally filter out the empty `List` so `switchIfEmpty` can switch over to the alternatives:

```
return allDatas.take(1).filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
       .switchIfEmpty(datas())
       .doOnNext(datas -> userStoreDao.insert(datas));
```