# RxJava call the network when database is empty

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava, Room and Retrofit to accomplish Repository pattern in Android. Everything is working except this one thing. I have implemented `SearchView` for searching data. Now when search view text changes I call search method. here is how it looks like

```
mLocal.searchMovies(query) //returns Single
mRemote.searchMovies(query) //returns Single

public Single<List<MovieEntity>> search(String query) {
    return mLocal.searchMovies(query)
        .toMaybe()
        .switchIfEmpty(mRemote.searchMovies(query)
        .map(data -> {
            mLocal.saveAll(data);
            return data;
        }));
}
```

`mLocal` queries the room database and `mRemote` calls retrofit to fetch data from REST API. The problem is, this only calls mLocal and when room returns empty row network call is not initiated. I have tried everything I possibly and read many articles but I cannot understand how to get it work.

Each of mLocal and mRemote works fine. Only chaining them does not accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation of my problem is the same as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571440/709683). I will copy relevant part and post my working piece of code after applying it.

Note: I changed to Flowable from Single/MayBe. am not sure how much it affects the original code, hadn't I changed the type of Observables.

> Based on the OP's feedback, the allDatas source was infinite but
>   returned an empty List. The resolution was to apply at least take(1)
>   to get exactly one response from allDatas and then optionally filter
>   out the empty List so switchIfEmpty can switch over to the
>   alternatives

```
public Flowable<List<MovieEntity>> getMovies() {
        return mLocal.allMovies().take(1)
                .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
                .switchIfEmpty(mRemote.allMovies()
                                .doOnNext(data -> mLocal.saveAll(data))
                        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your chain does not work because `.toMaybe()` from `Single` cannot produce `Maybe.empty()`, which is the result required to have `.switchIfEmpty` take effect.

You will either need to replace it with `Single.onErrorResume` so the error condition from a missing entry results in the remote query, or make it return `Maybe` to accurately represent the tristate of `<Result,NotCached,Error>`.